# How to supply an initial value to an individual Field in redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to build a form using `FieldArrays` from redux-form. Each field in the `fields` array needs to have an "order" field. I want to prepopulate this field with a default/initial value. I know how to supply `initialValues` to the form, but cannot figure out how to do it for an individual `Field`.

```
const renderQuestion = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => (
  <ul>

    {fields.map((question, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <button type="button" title="Remove Question" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>
          x
        </button>
        <h4>Question #{index + 1}</h4>
        <Field 
          name={`${question}.order`} 
          value={index + 1} // This line is an example to what I am trying to achieve
          type="number" 
          component={renderField} 
          label="Order" />
        <Field name={`${question}.prompt`} type="text" component={renderField} label="Prompt" />        
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

const QuizStepAddForm = props => {
      ...
      <FieldArray name="questions" component={renderQuestion} />
      ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Field meta={{initial: `${index + 1}}} />
```

https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/docs/api/field.md/#-code-meta-initial-any-code-

Comment: No kidding :) . Thanks!

Comment: Thank you again @kngroo. Can you please help me one more time? Can you tell me how I can properly supply this `initial` value to a wrapped component - `renderField`, so that this initial value will be a starting point which user can change. I have tried to make it work this way: `<input value={meta.initial}...`. It did not work

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You want to pass in some initial value as a prop to a wrapper component which wraps `<Field>`? You may want to read about controlled and uncontrolled components here: 

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components